# Creating a view, using more than symbol on text causing issue

Tags: sql, view, inner-join

I need to create a View. My query is giving me perfect results, as I convert this into a View,its showing the error: **'Error in list of function arguments: '<' not recognized. SQL text cannot be represented in the grid pane and diagram pane.'**

MY DATA: 
I have a list of airport table: Departure Airport and Destination Airport.  I want a unique list of these airports, in alphabetical order:
e.g.

[image]

Then I want to join this to another table, joining this twice to get information for both the Departure Airport and Destination Airport

> > > [image: <code>enter code here</code>]

I think the error is caused by the use of < when putting the airports in alphabetical order.  But I'm not to sure.

Comment: Edit your question and add (1) a database tag.  (2) the SQL code as TEXT in the question.  Who could read that?

Comment: Yes, you cannot have a string < another since it is not numeric. Try adding an ORDER BY clause(s)